# Meta (og?) tags needed for LinkedIn "Add Media"

Tags: html, metadata, linkedin-api, meta-tags

I tried to add a link to my profile on LinkedIn which I thought would allow me to share my portfolio website but there's a few issues. Mainly the image is out of proportion and also when clicking "view source", which I'd imagine should load the website, it just hangs.

I have no specific LinkedIn metadata in my `head`, so I imagine that's the issue. The image/text that is pulled in must be from the metadata I do have, which is related to Twitter and it doesn't fit.

Can someone advise me on the tags/info I should be declaring in the `head` of my website to get this to work?

Here is the metadata I'm currently using:

```html
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" sizes="32x32">

<!--iOS -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/site/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/img/site/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/img/site/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/img/site/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">

<!-- Facebook/Twitter -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@twitterusername">
<meta name="twitter:url" property="og:url" content="https://mywebsite.com">
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" content="Title of who I am and what jobs I do.">
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" content="A bit more information on what I specialise in and any extra additional info.">
<meta name="twitter:image" property="og:image" content="/img/site/social-logo.png">

<!-- Windows -->
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/img/site/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
```

It's not the end of the world but it's annoying! I put in a few support tickets but they were closed and moved assigned as a 'unique case' or something - then I was advised to come here.

Comment: This article [Improve content sharing with Open Graph](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The meta looks similar to what I've used for Twitter. So my only concern would be adding `property="og:title"` would maybe overwrite the existing tags? Or would I need to specify a `meta name=""` for LinkedIn?